# How do I use a std::map to change a vector of strings into another vector of characters?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap, decoder

I am am trying to make a decoder where you input the words comprising the NATO phonetic alphabet, and have it eventually spit out the translated sentences, only the actual "switcher" is not made.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<char, string> NATOMap = { {' ',"-"}, {'a', "alfa"}, {'b', "bravo"}, {'c', "charlie"}, {'d', "delta"}, {'e', "echo"}, {'f', "foxtrot"}, {'g',"golf"}, {'h',"hotel"}, {'i',"india"}, {'j', "juliett"}, {'k', "kilo"}, {'l', "lima"}, {'m',"mike"}, {'n', "november"}, {'o', "oscar"}, {'p', "papa"}, {'q',"quebec"}, {'r', "romeo"}, {'s',"sierra"}, {'t', "tango"}, {'u', "uniform"}, {'v',"victor"}, {'w',"whiskey"}, {'x',"xray"}, {'y',"yankee"}, {'z', "zulu"} };
    
    //this input comes from a file, placed here for easier testing
    string Dinpustring = "hotel echo lima lima oscar - whiskey oscar romeo lima delta";
    
    //split text
    string temp;
    stringstream ss(Dinpustring);
    vector<string> inputDxt;
    while (getline(ss, temp, ' ')) {
        inputDxt.push_back(temp);
    }
    //spit out text (testing purpouses)
    cout << "text get:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < inputDxt.size(); i++) {
        cout << inputDxt[i] << endl;
    }
    
    //switcher(probably contains loops)??
    
    
    //not necessary for here, only to show where its supposed to end up
        fstream Doutfile3;
    Doutfile3.open("Dencoded.txt", ios::out, ios::trunc);
    if (outfile3.is_open()) {
        outfile3 << outputDxt;
    }
    outfile3.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I have not previously worked with maps before, I barely got acquainted with vectors somewhat, so I have no idea where to at least start from; the rest of the code I have tested and know to work.

Comment: For starters, you want to flip the key and value of your map so you can look up characters by their long name. After that it is a matter of using the `[]` operator to index the map by word. Once you have that working, consider using the `.find` method instead, as that will tell you if the word is valid or not.

Comment: I get the goal is to learn about `map`s; just to be sure, may I ask if you are aware this decoding/encoding NATO alphabet could be done with a `std::array` (much simpler, faster container)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map is the wrong way around.
If your input is made of NATO words, it should be `map<string, char>`.
The first template argument is the *key*, i.e. what you look up, and the second argument is the *value*, i.e. the value associated with the looked-up key.

Since order doesn't matter here, you could use `unordered_map` just as well as `map`.

```cpp
// make this global
const std::unordered_map<std::string, char> NATOMap = {
    {"-", ' '}, {"alfa", 'a'}, {"bravo", 'b'}, /* ... */
};
```

Also, you should use `ss >> temp`, not `getline(ss, temp, ' ')` to read each word. `getline` does not handle multiple consecutive spaces nicely and gives you empty strings in such cases.

Then:

```cpp
// C++11
std::string decode(const std::vector<std::string>& words) {
    std::string result;
    for (const auto& word : words) {
        auto it = NATOmap.find(word);
        // If the word wasn't found, we push a '?' character.
        // You could also throw an exception in this case.
        result.push_back(it == NATOmap.end() ? '?' : it->second);
    }
    return result;
}

// C++23
std::string decode(std::span<const std::string> words) {
    return {std::from_range, words | std::views::transform([](const auto& word) {
        auto it = NATOmap.find(word);
        return it == NATOmap.end() ? '?' : it->second;
    })};
}

std::vector<std::string> inputDxt; // vector containing all input words
// fill inputDxt ...
std::cout << decode(inputDxt) << '\n';
```

Comment: The reason for arranging my `map` like that is because I was using it in a similar encoder in the same code, do I need to make two `map`'s or can I use the same one even if clunkier?

Comment: @Cool_cricri you could just make two maps. Just make a second one where the keys and values are swapped.

Comment: Tried to put in the C++23 code as-is, but it does not like the first like, with the errors saying "expected a `;` at the `words) {`, and `span` and `words` say they are unidentified

Comment: You need to include `<span>` and `<ranges>` to make it work. Even with that, I don't think any compiler implements `std::from_range` yet, so you'll need to store the view in a variable first and then `return {v.begin(), v.end()}`.

Comment: Added `<span>` and `<ranges>` but still nothing, it just does not want to identify(?) `span<const string> words`. I am using Visual studio 2022.

Comment: tried the C++11, but it still does not like the `) {` of the first line

Comment: @Cool_cricri with the most recent update, it should work for clang-trunk. https://godbolt.org/z/nbfznvxdf For GCC and MSVC, you probably need the aforementioned `{view.begin(), view.end()}` because `std::from_range` isn't a thing yet. I've also tested the C++11 version, and it should work now.

Comment: hate to sound like a broken record but so far my only problem has been :
`<source>:32:56: error: function definition is not allowed here
   32 | std::string decode(std::span<const std::string> words) {
`

Comment: @Cool_cricri that sounds like you have mismatched braces or something. The code prior to `decode` should be responsible for that. In any case, you should try to post a reproducible example of that, e.g. on compiler explorer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256599/discussion-between-cool-cricri-and-jan-schultke).

Answer (score 2):

A `std::map` is a data structure that sets a relationship between two things: a key and a value. In your example, the keys (`char`) `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. The corresponding values (`string`) for these keys are `"alfa"`, `"bravo"`, etc. (respectively).

To obtain the value associated to a key, you should do: `NATOMap['a']` (would return `"alfa"`).

In your case, you need the inverse mapping, i.e.: given a value, obtain the associated key. If this is really all you need to do, I suggest to invert your map and define it as: `{ {"alfa", 'a'}, {"bravo", 'b' }`, etc.
Then, you can do: `NATOMap["alfa"]` to obtain `'a'`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, there is no need to use `std::map` to decode the NATO phonetic alphabet speak. The first character of the long name is the character that the long name encodes, so just output that.

Here is how one could do that:

```
std::string natoWord;
while (std::cin >> natoWord) {
  if (natoWord == "-") 
    std::cout << " ";
  else 
    std::cout << natoWord[0];
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong since it would decode `garbage` as successfully as `golf`. You need to check the input against the list of NATO words.

Comment: @Atmo Quite the contrary. The code features *error recovery* --- it successfully receives messages from people who forget parts of the official alphabet and use makeshift code words, such as garbage instead of golf. And trust me, this does happen in real life.